# How to find the name property from an array of Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, dictionary

I am trying to get the value from an array of objects given the id, but I am not able to make it working. The problem is that I have an array of objects, so I don't know how to iterate over them. I know using the .map method could be a possible solution, but I'm new on this.

my method is that given a Id, it has to return me the name from the same object.
[image]

How could I iterate over them? I am using this actually:

```
getName(field_id: any): any {
var aux = 0;

  var obj = this.customFields[aux].filter(function (obj) {
    return obj.name === field_id;       
  })[0];
  aux ++;
}
```

where aux is an iterator. Ofc is not working.

Comment: var search=36;for(var i=0;i<array.length();i++){if(array[i].id=search){console.log("Here I am!");break;}}

Comment: Hi Simon, the problem is that I can not do the array.length. I just can do it if I do array[0].length()

Comment: Instead of using `Array.prototype.filter` and plucking the first element you can also use [`Array.prototype.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find?v=example) which will do that for you.

Comment: How come you can't use array.length? If it's an array of objects it should work (as in if it doesn't something is seriously wrong)... I'm assuming you have something like var array = [{id:36},{id:35}];

Comment: length is not a function, so for array # of items use `.length`

Comment: and for objects you can't use length. It will be undefined.

Comment: @yezzz is right btw, .length isn't a function and objects don't have the length variable so it's undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

considering array containing the objects, you can just use the filter function, no neeed to use the indexer

```js
var arr = [
  {id: 1, name: "something"},
  {id: 2, name: "something1"},
  {id: 3, name: "something2"},
  {id: 4, name: "something3"},
  {id: 5, name: "something4"}
]
var id=3
var obj = arr.filter(function(obj) {

  return obj.id === id;
})
console.log(obj[0].name)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is that you compare the name with the id. If you want to avoid loops:

```
// This find the correct entry corresponding to the id you are looking for
var correctField = this.customFields.find(function(field) {
  return field.id === field_id;
});
// Then you get the name from the entry
var nameToFind = correctField && correctField.name;
```

You might have to replace find depending on your browser support.

A way to replace it:
    this.customFields.filter()[0]

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `for loop` as below

```
var arr = [{id:1,name:"abc"},{id:2,name:"pqr"},{id:3,name:"lmn"}]

function getName(id){
  for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
    if(arr[i].id==id)
      return arr[i].name;
   return null 
}

getName(2);// pqr
```